# Launching magento 2 application(s) in chrome and firefox results in DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

Tags: magento2, chrome-browser

Steps taken:

1. Followed warden doc. howto initialize an environment for setup of
   the Magento 2 application for local development. See
   https://docs.warden.dev/environments/initializing.html
2. Launch a magento application in chrome/firefox:

   https://app.exampleproject.test/
   https://app.exampleproject.test/backend/
   https://rabbitmq.exampleproject.test/
   https://elasticsearch.exampleproject.test/

Result: Chrome/firefox

- This site can’t be reached. Check if there is a typo in app.exampleprj.test.
  DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

[image]I'm sure there is **no** typo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure the DNS resolver.

https://docs.warden.dev/configuration/dns-resolver.html#systemd-resolved

Run these commands to configure systemd-resolved:

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/systemd/resolved.conf.d
echo -e "[Resolve]\nDNS=127.0.0.1\nDomains=~test\n" \
  | sudo tee /etc/systemd/resolved.conf.d/warden.conf > /dev/null
sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved
```